# Include SVG File inline in Jekyll/Liquid

Tags: templates, svg, include, jekyll, liquid

I want to leverage jekyll/liquid's `{% include %}` utility to inject the contents of an external svg file into an html file.

example.html:

```
{% include img/about.svg %}
```

img/about.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="753px" height="594px" viewBox="0 0 753 594" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>img/about</title>
    <defs>
        <rect id="path-1" x="0" y="0" width="660" height="110"></rect>
    </defs>
    <g id="img/about" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="background" transform="translate(20.000000, 234.130000)">
            <path id="Path" d="M684.394158,-2.55788351 L684.533335,-2.48650075 L704.533335,8.76349925 L707.63227,10.5066503 L704.533335,12.2498014 L684.533335,23.4998014 C683.570619,24.041329 682.351189,23.6998886 681.809661,22.7371728 C681.29392,21.8203007 681.579058,20.670581 682.439013,20.095371 L682.57229,20.0134993 L695.918,12.506 L21,12.5066503 C19.8954305,12.5066503 19,11.6112198 19,10.5066503 C19,9.45228853 19.8158778,8.58848521 20.8507377,8.51213606 L21,8.50665033 L695.918,8.506 L682.57229,0.999801402 C681.655417,0.484060819 681.30206,-0.646557382 681.738278,-1.58469589 L681.809661,-1.72387215 C682.325402,-2.6407443 683.45602,-2.99410143 684.394158,-2.55788351 Z" fill="#00AD00" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
            <circle id="experience-dot" stroke="#00AD00" stroke-width="4" fill="#1C1C1C" cx="10.5" cy="10.5" r="10.5"></circle>
        </g>
        <g id="companies-mask" transform="translate(42.000000, 198.000000)">
            <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
                <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
            </mask>
            <g id="Rectangle"></g>
            .... etc ....
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

—————

I get an error:

```
Liquid Exception: Invalid syntax for include tag. File contains invalid characters or sequences: img/about.svg Valid syntax: {% include file.ext param='value' param2='value' %} in /example.html
```

Pasting the svg directly into the html works as expected, but using include results in the above error. How can I use `{% include %}` to inject the external svg into my jekyll/liquid template?